# $n^{th}$ roots and $e$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In Churchill's book on complex variables, the $n^{th}$ root of $e$ is defined to be $e^{1/n}$. A comment is made that in this respect $e$ is treated differently than the $n^{th}$ roots of other complex numbers (in the sense that there are typically n roots of the nth root of a number in complex analysis rather than just one as in the case of $e$).

I am curious why $e$ is treated so differently. Is there an obvious reason/motivation why?

Edit: The section from Churchill is,

As anticipated earlier, we define here the exponential function $e^z$ by writing
$$ e^z = e^xe^{iy}\ \ \ \ \ \ (z = x + iy)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
where Euler's formula
$$ e^{iy} = \cos y + i\sin y$$
is used and $y$ is to be taken in radians. We see from this definition that $e^z$ reduces to the usual exponential function in calculus when $y=0$; and, following the convention used in calculus, we often write $\exp z$ for $e^z$.

Note that since the *positive* $n$th root $\sqrt[n]{e}$ of $e$ is assigned to $e^x$ when $x = 1/n$ ($n = 2,3,\ldots$), expression (1) tells us that the complex exponential function $e^z$ is also $\sqrt[n]{e}$ when $z = 1/n$ ($n = 2,3,\ldots$). This is an exception to the convention that would ordinarily require us to interpret $e^{1/n}$ as the set of $n$th roots of $e$.

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't sound right. What page of Churchill's book are you looking at?

Comment: Apart from the Routine $\TeX$ edit, I have made vars "variables". Please do not make this place into a SMS chat. This is a dedicated forum for Math Q&A. Further, any signature or tagline for the posts is advised against, by the faq. So, I have removed it.

Comment: The constant $e$ actually *does* have $n$ distinct $n$-th roots, for all $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. The only number in all of $\mathbb{C}$ without such a property is $0$. I'm not familiar with Churchill - is your parenthetical your own understanding or something specifically stated by the author? Generally in complex analysis the function $z\to z^{1/n}$ is chosen with a particular [branch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts) in mind rather than assumed multi-valued. // Could you transcribe the comment in full, if possible?

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that $f(z)=z^{1/n}$ is taken multi-valued while $e^w$ is defined to be the exponential, given by the usual power series, and hence takes on only one value.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, which I'll have to digest. To answer Alvaro's question though, the comment is made in chapter 3, section 28, pg 87 (of 7th edition), where I quote:

Comment: @MattBrenneman: ... but no quote is visible to me.  I'd like to see that quote.  There doesn't seem to be anything in that section of the 2nd edition (which is what I have) that would fit your description.

Comment: @MattBrenneman and everyone else! I've added the passage in the book. Hopefully it's everything you mentioned, and if not please feel free to add (or emphasize) any other parts!

Answer (score 1):

The natural exponential function is defined by 
$$\exp(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {z^n\over n!}.$$
This is an entire function. It is not hard to show it has all of the expected properties.

To define $z^w$ you must define something like
$$z^w = \exp(z\log(w)).$$

Unfortunately, the exponential function is $2\pi i$-periodic.  Therefore it is not 1-1, so the business of defining a logarithm function becomes tricky. You must choose a domain to restrict the exponential function to so it is 1-1. And there the trouble begins. But where the trouble begins, complex analysis begins in all of its beauty and elegance.

I quote one of my grad school professors, Sidney Graham, who said, 
"There are those who say that the study of complex variables is the study of the logarithm function."

Answer (score 1):

The point is that we want "the" exponential function to be single-valued.  If you want to write $\exp(1/n)$ as ${\rm e}^{1/n}$, that singles out one "$n$'th root of e".  There are still $n$ $n$'th roots of e, it's just that only one of them is written as ${\rm e}^{1/n}$.